# What's the difference between "word = line.split()" and "for word in line.split()"?

Tags: python, split

I'm new to programming and this is my first question here. I feel it might be a very silly beginner doubt, but here goes.

On multiple occasions, I've typed out the whole code right except for this one line, on which I make the same mistake every time.

Could someone please explain to me what the computer understands when I type each of the following lines, and what the difference is?

```
word = line.split()
for word in line.split()
```

The difference between the expected and my actual output is just because I typed the former instead of the latter:

[image]

Comment: for word = line.split() will not even run, so i don't think that is what you typed.

Comment: when you do `word = line.split()` `word` will be the `resultant list`

Comment: `line.split()` will return a list. `word = line.split()` will assign that list to the variable `word` (probably not a helpful name in the context - `words` would be better), whereas `for word in line.split():` will iterate over the list, assigning each element in turn to the variable `word` inside the loop.

Comment: when you do `for word in line.split()`  it means you are looping through the `resultant list which is line.split()`

Comment: Welcome Sahaj, we encourage researching before posting a new question. Your answer is already in many tutorials, here are the links for python's docs on [string.split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) and [for statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
word = line.split()
```

This will split the `line` variable (using the default "any amount of white space" separator) and give you back a *list* of words built from it. You then bind the variable `word` to that list.

On the other hand:

```
for word in line.split()
```

initially does the same thing the previous command did (splitting the line to get a list) but, instead of binding the `word` variable to that entire list, it iterates *over* the list, binding `word` to *each* string in the list in turn.

The following transcript hopefully makes this clearer:

```
>>> line = 'pax   is   good-looking'

>>> word = line.split() ; print(word)
['pax', 'is', 'good-looking']

>>> for word in line.split(): print(word)
...
pax
is
good-looking
```

Comment: I couldn't comment on the accuracy of the text inside the string itself(!), but the rest is verifiably correct. Have an upvote on me to compensate for that puzzling downvote.

Answer (score 0):

The split() is a separator method.
`word = line.split()` will return a list by splitting line into words where `' '` is present (as it is the default separator.)
`for word in line.split()` will iterate over that list (line.split()).
Here is an example for clarification.

```
line = "Stackoverflow is amazing"
word = line.split()
print(word)
>>>['Stackoverflow','is','amazing']

for word in line.split():
    print(word)
>>>
'Stackoverflow'
'is'
'amazing'
```